# wrong parameter passes to a function and it still works (customized serialization)

Tags: java, function, serialization, call, signature

I have a class which implements Serializable and overrides its functions - writeObject and readObject.

How is it that while calling function readObject() there is no parameter passed but while defining the overridden there is a parameter. Its not even a parameter followed by any number of parameters signature [ like: (int i...)]

How is this code working:

```
//I understand this part:

package CustomizedSerialization;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class Cat implements Serializable
{
    int k = 30;
    int j = 10;
    char c = 'c';
}


package CustomizedSerialization;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.Serializable;

public class Dog2 implements Serializable 
{

    transient Cat c = new Cat();

    private void writeObject(ObjectOutputStream oos) throws IOException
    {
        int x = c.j;
        oos.writeInt(x);
    }
```

*********marked line 1a - input parameter of readObject********

```
    private void readObject(ObjectInputStream ois) throws ClassNotFoundException, IOException
    {
        ois.defaultReadObject();

        c = new Cat();


    }

}

package CustomizedSerialization;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;

public class SerializeDemo2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException 
    {

        Dog2 d = new Dog2();

        System.out.println("Before serialization "+ d.c.j);
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("C:\\serializedFile.ser");
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos); 

        oos.writeObject(d);



        System.out.println("After serialization");
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("C:\\serializedFile.ser");        
        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
```

*********marked line 1a - input parameter of readObject********

```
        Dog2 d1 = (Dog2) ois.readObject();

        System.out.println(d1.c.j);
        System.out.println(d1.c.c);
    }

}
```

How is "line marked 1 a" in programs (Dog2 and SerializeDemo2) working? SerializeDemo2 calls function readObject of class Dog2 without any parameter but while defining the called function (readObject) in class Dog2, it has an input parameter. How is it not throwing error.

Comment: `ois` is an `ObjectInputStream`.  `ois.readObject()` calls the function `readObject` of class `ObjectInputStream`, not of class `Dog2`.

Comment: on _marked line 1a_ you are invoking `readObject()` on `ObjectInputStream` and not on your object.

Comment: if it is invoking readObject() of ObjectInputStream and not Dog2, then if i remove line "ois.defaultReadObject();" from readObject function of Dog2, program does not run, it throws an error. I have some reachable code in readObject() of class Dog 2 and without that reachable code, this program does not work. So readObject() of class Dog2 is getting invoked and not ObejctInputStreams (I am casting ObjectInputStream object - "ois" to Dog2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ObjectInputStream.readObject()` with no parameters calls the deserialized object's `readObject(ObjectInputStream ois)` method, if it exists, and that in turn should call `ObjectInputStream.defaultReadObject()`. These are three distinct methods, and none of them is an override of any other.

Comment: @KhushbooSingh There is no connection between 'not overriding' and 'how are we able to cast?' Unclear what you're asking.

Comment: @KushbooSingh I have no idea what you mean by `ObjectInputStream's Object ois`. `ois` is an `ObjectInputStream`, not an `Object`. All you need to know is that `ObjectInputStream.readObject()` creates an object of the correct type.

Comment: @KhushbooSingh You aren't making any sense.  `ois` **isn't** being cast to `Dog2`. The *result* of `ois.readObject()` is being cast to `Dog2`.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up. Makes sense now. Also, can you please attach an oracle document to refer to your explanation of how ObjectInputStream.readObject() with no parameters calls the deserialized object's readObject(ObjectInputStream ois). I need to know if ObjectInputStream.readObject internally calls readObject of class Dog2? So that your explanation makes sense, even though it is right, it would be great to know how? thanks

Comment: @KhushbooSingh It does. I've already answered that. In my answer. Above. You can find all this in the Object Serialization Specification. NB Your confusion about the casting was due to misreading it as `((Dog2)ois).readObject()` when it is really `(Dog2)(ois.readObject())`. Just a syntax misunderstanding.

Comment: and can someone explain to me what is wrong with the quality of question? Else, atleast please point me to a post which explains how ObjectInputStream.readObject() internally calls deserialized Object's readObject()?can someone atleast point me to an Oracle document which tells us that ObjectInputStream's readObject calls deserialized Object's readObject? Thanks

Comment: I am willing to take a downvote and learn from my mistakes. but if  downvote is about personal opinion not backed by any technical document or valid explanation, i do not know what to learn from that downvote for my future questions?

Comment: @KhushbooSingh I have just pointed you exactly to *the* document which explains it. I'm surprised you hadn't already read it: otherwise it is difficult to understand where you got the idea of a custom `readObject()` method from, or why you bothered to write it if you didn't think it was going to get called. You are now embarked on a completely different question from your original question, which was essentially about a syntax misunderstanding, as I have also already just told you. You really shouldn't be surprised when a question exhibiting such confusions attracts downvotes and close votes.

Comment: those were comments, not part of original question. If i could delete my comment, this downvote does not explain itself. This pretty much explains gamification rules - downvote on question quality and "flag" comments, if that was possible. Now, about "the" document. Can you please share with me link for the same? Thanks!

Comment: As for where I got idea about custom readObject(). I was obviously referring to "Working with Inheritance" of OCAJP material, which does not explain on how ObjectInputStream's readObject() calls deserialized object's readObject(ObjectInputStream ois).

Comment: Thank you I will google. Everything apart, thank you for pointing me to right direction. I would not have guessed it and I did do my searching. thanks!

Comment: There is nothing 'obvious' about getting it from the OCAJP. You didn't mention any sources in your question.

Comment: I am referring to this document: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/platform/serialization/spec/input.html; Please correct me if I am wrong, but I still do not see the internal code snippet wherein ObjectInputStream's readObject() internally calls readObject with parameter. If I am referring to a wrong document, please correct me. Thank you.